# PostgreSQL query on 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Trying to write query in **PostgreSql**, for following scenario:

*Websites with single property associated with it, and having KEY1, KEY2, KEY4 is NOT NULL.*

```
Table: websites 
id sub_domain name
1  abc.com    abc
2  pqr.com    pqr
3  xyz.com    xyz
4  ttt.com    ttt
5  sss.com    sss
6  xxx.com    xxx
7  yyy.com    yyy
8  zzz.com    zzz
9  aaa.com    aaa

Table: website_properties
id website_id property_id
1  1          1
2  1          2
3  2          1
4  3          1
5  4          3
6  5          4
7  6          3
8  7          1
9  7          2
10 8          5
11 9          6

Table: property_preferences
property_id key   value
1           KEY1   V1
2           KEY2   V2
3           KEY1   V3 
4           KEY3   V3
5           KEY4   V4
6           KEY4   NULL

EXPECTED OUTPUT
id sub_domain name
2  pqr.com    pqr
3  xyz.com    xyz
4  ttt.com    ttt
6  xxx.com    xxx
8  zzz.com    zzz
```

**EXPLAINATION for expected output:**

- website id 1 and 7 are going to eliminate because these websites having more than 1 property associated.
- website id 9 eliminated because property associated with this is 6 and having KEY4 is NULL.
- website id 5 is eliminated because we are not expecting website with property with KEY3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
select w.id, w.sub_domain, w.name
from websites w
join website_properties wp on wp.website_id = w.id
join property_preferences pp on pp.property_id = wp.property_id
where (select count(website_id) from website_properties wp where wp.website_id = w.id) = 1
and (key in ('KEY1', 'KEY2', 'KEY4') and value is not null);
-- based on your comment to this answer:
-- and (key in ('KEY1', 'KEY2', 'KEY3') and value is not null);
-- expects with KEY1, KEY2, KEY4 and not null
```

Comment: partially correct, just need this now: having KEY1, KEY2, KEY4 and that keys should not be NULL

Comment: edited your answer; this should be correct query, i guess.

Comment: or negated like this: *and (key != 'KEY3' and value is not null)*